# Error: Undefined offset: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Quiero imprimir datos en label's luego de consultarlos mediante *MySQL*, pero me sale este error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in **prueba.php** on line **79**
> **Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **/prueba.php** on line **79**

Mi código es este en *PHP*:

```
<?php 

  $db = new Database('base');

  $empresa = @$_GET['empresa'];
  $codigo = @$_GET['codigo'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM basePrueba WHERE (empresa = ? AND codigo = ?)";

$values = [
  [$empresa, 's'],
  [$codigo, 's']
];
/** */
/*$result = $db->select($query, $values) or die (mysqli_error($query, $values));*/

$result = $db->select($query, $values);
```

Y el *HTML* el siguiente:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
          <h4 class="text-center">Formulario Dinámico</h4>
          <form method="get"  class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="lastName">Código:</label>
                <input type="text" name="codigo" class="form-control" id="codigo" placeholder="" value="" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Valid last name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button onclick="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block col-md-10" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" type="submit">Buscar</button>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" value="<?= $result[0]['nombre'] ?>" class="form-control" value="" id="username" readonly="readonly" placeholder="ID" required>
                </div>
              </div>
```

El error es acá:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= $result[0]['nombre'] ?>" class="form-control" value="" id="username" readonly="readonly" placeholder="ID" required/>
```

Intenté poner `isset ( isset($result[0]['nombre']) )` pero cuando cargo datos, aparece un 1 en la casilla donde se supone tiene que aparecer el dato.

> **Nota:** Eliminé algunos campos de *HTML* para hacer corto el post.

Comment: Mira que datos trae `$result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías usar `@` para omitir mensajes de error o advertencias y, definitivamente, debes validar que hay datos antes de tratar de ejecutar una consulta.

Puedes usar asignación ternaria, que es como un `if`, pero resumido:

```
$variable = (condicion) ? 'valor si verdadero' : 'valor si falso';
```

O bien, el operador [de fusión *null*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), que es un poco más sencillo y está disponible a partir de PHP 7+:

```
$variable = $otra_variable ?? 'Valor si "$otra_variable" no está definida';
```

La segunda opción me parece más adecuada, a menos que estés usando una versión anterior de PHP. Además, te recomiendo crear una variable `$nombre`, que vas a usar independientemente de que se hayan obtenido resultados en la consulta o no.

```
<?php 

  $db = new Database('base');

  // Definir variable
  $nombre = '';

  // Obtener datos o asignar cadena vacía si no se proporcionaron
  $empresa = $_GET['empresa'] ?? '';
  $codigo = $_GET['codigo'] : '';

  // Validar datos
  if($empresa == '' || $codigo == '') {
      // Hay datos vacíos, no se debe ejecutar la consulta
      // Probablemente quieras mostrar un mensaje
      echo '<p>Debes proporcionar empresa y código.</p>';
  } else {
      // Armar consulta y ejecutar, solicitando solo los campos necesarios en lugar de * que selecciona todo:
      $query = "SELECT nombre FROM basePrueba WHERE (empresa = ? AND codigo = ?)";
      $values = [
        [$empresa, 's'],
        [$codigo, 's']
      ];
  
      $result = $db->select($query, $values);
      // Al parecer, el método select() devuelve un arreglo
      // Contar filas obtenidas
      if(count($result) > 0) {
          // Hay resultados, actualizar variable
          $nombre = $result[0]['nombre'];
      } else {
          echo '<p>No se encontraron resultados con esa empresa y código.</p>';
      }
  }
  // Ahora sí, ya puedes armar el HTML con los datos obtenidos
```

Finalmente, solo debes cambiar el *input* para usar `$nombre` en lugar del elemento de resultados.

```
<input type="text" value="<?= $nombre ?>" class="form-control" value="" id="username" readonly="readonly" placeholder="ID" required>
```

De esta forma garantizas que siempre tendrás un valor para mostrar en el *input*, evitando cualquier posible error en la recepción de datos.